# Check for new user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I want to know when a user logs in via a provider(twitter,facebook,etc...) If he is a new user. If so then add his data to my firebase.. Currently i have read this:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html

And it tells me to do:

```
var isNewUser = true;
```

Then check by saying

```
if(authData && isNewUser){
//This is a new user
}
```

But it dosent work... I logged in with the same account but it tells me its a new user...

Comment: The example to which you are referring clearly states that `isNewUser` is a simulated value. You will need to determine if they're a new user on your own.

Comment: The example also states ways to check whether or not the user is new, which may help you implement your program. I quote from the example: "We would probably save a profile when we register new users on our site. We could also read the profile to see if it's null."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally with Firebase, you would have a /users node where you would store other data about your users

```
users
   user_id_0
     name: "Buck Murdock"
     email: "buck@moonbasealphabeta"
   user_id_1
     name: "Ted Striker"
     email: "ted@airplane.com"
```

The user_id is the Firebase assigned user id.

When a user starts to access your App, you would query your /users node to see if, for example, their email already exists. If not, then you create the user and add them to the /users node.

Oh - and refer to the section Storing User Data in the Firebase guide as you may have overlooked the comment

> // here we will just simulate this with an isNewUser boolean